# Can multiple EC2 workers "utilize" the same IP address?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

The setup:

- SQL for queueing jobs
- EC2 workers for running jobs (autoscaling via CloudWatch)

The problem:

As jobs are run, many of them require connecting to third-party systems that have very strict security policies.  As such, the only way to access these systems is by white-listing our worker's IP address in advance.  However, as new EC2 instances spin up they will (obviously) have different IP addresses.

What would it take to make all the workers' requests come from a single, static IP address? I don't see anything in AWS that covers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would probably need to run your instances inside a Virtual Private Cloud with a VPC router to where you can have control over the NAT translations for the machines.  Check teh documentation here as a starting point:

http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/

Comment: It looks like a VPC is what I need, but it's going to be tricky to configure.  Thanks for the push in the right direction!

Comment: @claviska, if you create a VPC using the "wizard", then you can have the wizard create the VPC for you with a NAT instance and route tables automatically configured. Give the NAT instance an Elastic IP and whitelist that EIP. Then launch your workers on the "private subnet" (which sends traffic to the internet through the NAT instance) and that's all you need.

Comment: Bruno, I did eventually get that setup exactly as you stated. My question would then be, how scalable is that? If all traffic goes through the NAT router, wouldn't it potentially bottleneck with many large transfers?